# The intersection numbers of torsion elements of $ \operatorname{Div}X $

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading about the Riemann-Roch inequality.

That is $$ l(D)+l(K_{X}-D) \geq \frac{1}{2}D(D-K_{X})+\chi(\mathcal{O}_{X}), $$ where $ X $ is a nonsingular projective surface with canonical class $ K_{X},\; D $ is an arbitrary divisor on $ X, $ and $ l(D) $ is the dimension of the vector space associated to $ D $.

The text contains the following statement:

> The intersection number of divisors $ D_{1},D_{2} \in \operatorname{Div}X $ depends on their images in $ \operatorname{Div}X/\operatorname{Div}^{a}X, $ where $ \operatorname{Div}^{a}X $ is the subgroup of divisors $ D $ algebraically equivalent to $ 0. $ We can also pass to the quotient by the torsion subgroup, **since torsion elements, of course, give zero intersection numbers.**

Why do torsion elements give zero intersection numbers?

Let $ R = \operatorname{Div}X, $ and $ T(R) $ is its torsion submodule, where $ \operatorname{Div}X $ is viewed as a vector space over $ k. $  If $ [D_{1}] = [D_{2}] \in R/T(R), $ then obviously $ D_{1}-D_{2} \in T(R), $ and therefore $ k_{1}(D_{1}-D_{2}) = 0. $

I'm not sure how to see from here that the intersection number of $ D_{1} $ and $ D_{2} $ is $ 0. $

Comment: Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are elements and $kP = 0$ with $k \ne 0$ so that $P$ is a torsion element. What do you get when you compute $k (P \cdot Q) = (kP) \cdot Q$? What's that tell you about $P \cdot Q$?

Comment: @JohnHughes I think it means that $ k(P\cdot Q) = 0. $ Does this mean that $ (P \cdot Q) = 0, $ so that $ P $ and $ Q $ do not intersect?

Comment: I assume that your intersection numbers lie in $\Bbb Z$ (they tend to in algebraic topology, for instance), and if $ab = 0$ in $\Bbb Z$, and $a \ne 0$, then $b  = 0$. As for "so that $P$ and $Q$ do not intersect"...no, that's not true: they may still intersect geometrically (like unit circles centered at $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$, for instance) but have zero as an algebraic intersection numbers (as my two circles do).